# How do you compute $R^2$ with a given model?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I see that the `LinearModelFit` function can give you the $R^2$ of the best fit, but I already have a model. I want to compare the data to the model (function) and have *Mathematica* tell me how good a fit it is.  That is, I have a function, `Mass[r]`, and I have a bunch of data, `data = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}`. How can I tell how well `Mass[r]` matches `data`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a possible solution if you already have a model object:

```
rsquared[list___, model_] := 
 1 - SquaredEuclideanDistance[list[[;; , 2]], 
   model /@ list[[;; , 1]]]/
  SquaredEuclideanDistance[list[[;; , 2]], Mean@list[[;; , 2]]]
```

Testing for the given data

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}};
mass = LinearModelFit[data, x, x];
rsquared[data, mass]
(*0.889474*)
```

Verifying with the built in `RSquared` functionality

```
mass["RSquared"]
(*0.889474*)
```

Alternatively, with any defined function:

```
model[r_] := 2.6*r
rsquared[data, model]
(*0.888421*)
```

Comment: Thank you.  It works like a charm.  So just to confirm, there's no built-in Mathematica operation that will do this?  It seems so basic.

Comment: A quick look around doesn't seem to indicate that there is a built in function.

Comment: For the denominator, you could instead use `((Length[list] - 1) Variance[list[[;;, 2]]])`.